# My VM all of a sudden stopped sending out emails (They stay stuck in the Queue folder). Nothing has been changed in configrations)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, dns, smtp

All of a sudden my SharePoint 2013 VM stopped sending emails. Had been fine for the longest. Nothing with configuration has changed.
All the mail stay stuck in the queue.

Here's the odd thing. I have a few snapshots that go back a month ago where it all worked well , I loaded them on and even they have the same issue as my current SharePoint 2013 VM.

**Some things to note:**
This is a test Dev Server with AD and DNS on it.
I am using Gmail for the SMTP.
Everything had been going on great for a few weeks and then suddenly mail stays in the queue. I do have internet connection.
The only thing I can think off that is relative to all snapshots older and current is the DNS. Any chance the DNS changed address affecting my VM?
If so how to check?
Thank you.

Comment: How did you configure Gmail for SMTP? SharePoint can't do that out-of-the-box, as it only allows Anonymous SMTP.

Comment: MHeld, here's how to https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yashgoel-msft/2012/10/26/configuring-outgoing-email-settings-in-sharepoint-with-gmail-smtp/